# Is a pure number like "3" a valid jobspec?

Tags: job-control

I was reading a book about Linux. It states that to bring a process to foreground, use the `fg` command and a percent sign (%) followed by the job number. I did some testing and found that it works as expected. But I also found that I can use a simple number as the jobspec, like `fg 3` (instead of `fg %3`), which can bring the third process to foreground, too. Is a simple number can be considered a valid jobspec?

Comment: In Bash, any of `fg 3`, `fg %3` or `%3` will bring job [3] back to foreground. If there is only one background job, `fg` will also bring it back. Regardless of the specification, none of those versions is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash seems to accept `fg 3` etc., but I'm not sure the documentation is too explicit about that.

The [description for `fg`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#Job-Control-Builtins) just says it takes a "jobspec", and [their description](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html#Job-Control-Basics) says "The character ‘%’ introduces a job specification (jobspec)." and the `%` seems included in all the examples.

The other shells I tried (Dash, ksh and zsh) didn't accept a plain number there, so it looks like a Bash-only thing.

Note that `kill` can take a jobspec or a process ID, so both `kill %3` and `kill 3` are valid, they just mean different things. Which also implies that in general, a plain number can't work as a jobspec, so perhaps better to stick with `%3`.

Comment: Thanks for the testing and the answer.